# Grails command not found

Tags: ubuntu, grails, sdk

After my laptop restart, my Grails cannot run as it become command not found even though I set the homepath of Grails_HOME and Java_home.

```
grails: command not found
```

I try to reinstall it with sdk, but it come out an error:

```
Stop! grails is not a valid candidate.
```

Anyone can help me with a solution?

Grails version 2.4.2

Comment: What is your GRAILS_HOME path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstall sdkman again and remove my network proxy at company now it works, thank you everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Append grails path till your `/bin` directory to your PATH variable in your `.bashrc`.

E.g.

```
PATH=$PATH:$GRAILS_HOME/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

Find in sdk location under archives folder any grails zip is present
if you are using mac then sdkman archive location will be like:
`/Users/<system_name>/.sdkman/archives`

if zip is present then try opening a new window in terminal or command prompt(whatever you are using) then again try installing grails with sdk like:
sdk install grails 2.4.2

The error mentioned above: `Stop! grails is not a valid candidate.` is removed when we restart the terminal.

if this didn't work, then paste the location of `GRAILS_HOME` path